# Define a RPC without function arguments and return value

Tags: grpc

Can I define a RPC in my `.proto` file that takes no function arguments and has no return value?

I tried

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

service Greeter {
   rpc GreetEveryone () returns () {} 
}
```

but I got two `Expected message type` errors when generating the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a well-known [`Empty` message type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Empty) that you could use as the return value and argument.  However, it is a good idea to define your own Empty message type so that if in the future you need to extend the RPC to carry additional data, you would be able to extend your own type while keeping the service API backward-compatible with old clients.